# How to Install Needed C# Solution's Reference/Package?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I got a C# source code for a project. I wanted to rebuild the project but it needs some Reference/Packages so it gave me build error (missing reference for some packages). I tried to install the package from NuGet one by one. But I couldn't find some packages in NuGet.

So, my questions are:

1. Is there any other source to find the missing package? I tried to
   Google, but the package name is only `WW` and `Azuria` (and it's not
   this one https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azuria, the project is not
   related to German Manga/Anime)
2. I am new to C# and .Net, is there something like `requirements.txt`
   like in Python project (that I can install all the dependencies with
   `pip install -e requirements.txt`.
3. Is it true that I only able to build a class file (DLL file) for C# but not a window application on Ubuntu? I tried to do my work on Ubuntu if possible.

Btw, I checked app.config, I found this lines

```
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WW" publicKeyToken="87d16b8f7b531b65" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.34.50" newVersion="3.5.34.50" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

but I am not sure where to get this WW.

Comment: It could be an internal nuget package source available to the project developer.

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich do you mean the previous project developer has its own packages that only available on his computer?

Comment: If you google publicKeyToken: 87d16b8f7b531b65 you will get some results from "Wout Ware" whatever it is...

Answer (score 2):

The `requirements.txt` equilivant is built in to the .csproj file, it is the xml elements that are labeled `<PackageReference Include="..." />`

Looking at the nuget repository for packages from "Wout Ware" like Peska mentioned shows [these packages](https://www.nuget.org/profiles/woutware) so there is likely in your csproj file that looks like

```
<PackageReference Include="WW.Cad.NetStandard" />
```

When you do the [`dotnet restore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-restore) command it gets the packages defined in the csproj file and their dependencies from the internet.